# How to print nodes in heap recursively

Tags: python, heap

Given heap as an array with keys , how to print all keys ? So far I got

```
def heapPrint (arr,i):
    if (len(arr) == 0 or len(arr) == 1):
        return
    if (left(i) > len(arr) or right(i) > len(arr)):
        return
    if (left(i) < len(arr) and right(i) < len(arr):
        print (arr[left(i)],arr[right(i)])
    heapPrint (arr,left(i))
    heapPrint (arr,right(i))
```

Isnt there any better solution where I could print just 1 node and not 2? Thanks

Comment: What's `left`? What's `right`? What's `i`? What's the value of `arr`? What's the expected output? Please read [mcve].

Comment: `left` returns index of left children, `right` returns index of right children , `i` is the index of a node and `arr` is heap with some values

Comment: Edit your question and show us what you want the output to look like for a sample heap that contains 7 nodes. I don't understand what you mean by "print just 1 node and not 2."

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
def heapPrint(arr, i)
    # if the index is larger than the heap length
    if i >= len(arr):
        return;

    # if it's a leaf node, then return
    if left(i) >= len(arr) and right(i) >= len(arr):
        return

    if left(i) < len(arr):
        print(arr[left(i)], end=' ')
    if right(i) < len(arr):
        print(arr[right(i)], end='')
    print('')

    # these calls will return immediately if the
    # index is too large.
    heapPrint(arr, left(i))
    heapPrint(arr, right(i))
```

My python skills are minimal, so there might be some syntax errors there, but that's the basic idea.